# Spring Boot Authorization

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security, unauthorized

I do not know how to be able to do request from endpoint localhost:8080/manage/**

First off before everything I go on my endpoint
localhost:8080/api/auth/register and I do enter my user that already have "ADMIN" role
with this JSON:

```json
{
  "username": "Admin",
  "password": "password"
}
```

Here is **UserModel** class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "users")
public class UserModel {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @DocumentReference
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Here is my **Role** class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
}
```

Then I try to add my product at endpoint
localhost:8080/manage/addProduct
with this JSON

```json
{
  "name": "monitor",
  "category": "electronic",
  "price": 1799.99,
  "imageUrl": "URL"
}
```

But I get unauthorised. What Am I doing wrong?

**ProductController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/manage")
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @PostMapping("/addProduct")
    public Product saveProduct(@RequestBody Product product){
        return productService.saveProduct(product);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/removeProduct/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> removeProduct(@PathVariable ObjectId id){
        return productService.deleteProduct(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/updateProduct/{id}")
    public Product updateProduct(@PathVariable ObjectId id, @RequestBody Product product) throws ServiceNotFoundException {
        return productService.updateProduct(id, product);
    }
}
```

**AuthController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private JWTGenerator jwtGenerator;
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserRepository userRepository,
                          RoleRepository roleRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, JWTGenerator jwtGenerator) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.jwtGenerator = jwtGenerator;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody AuthDto registerDto) {
        if(userRepository.existsByUsername(registerDto.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Username is taken");
        }

        UserModel user = new UserModel();
        user.setUsername(registerDto.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registerDto.getPassword()));

        Role roles = roleRepository.findByName("USER").orElse(null);
        user.setRoles(Collections.singletonList(roles));

        userRepository.save(user);
        ResponseEntity<AuthResponseDTO> tokenResponse = login(registerDto, httpServletResponse);

        if (tokenResponse != null && tokenResponse.getBody() != null) {
            String token = tokenResponse.getBody().getAccessToken();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthResponseDTO(token));
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("An error occurred");
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthResponseDTO> login(@RequestBody AuthDto loginDto, HttpServletResponse response){
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginDto.getUsername(),
                        loginDto.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String token = jwtGenerator.generateToken(authentication);
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("jwtToken", token);

        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setMaxAge(7200);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setSecure(true);

        response.addCookie(cookie);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new AuthResponseDTO(token), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<String> logout(HttpServletResponse response){
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("jwtToken", null);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        response.addCookie(cookie);

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Logged out successfully");
    }

}
```

**CustomUserDetailService**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserModel user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(()
                -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found Exception"));
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
    }

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(List<Role> roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

**JWTAuthenticationFilter**

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JWTGenerator tokenGenerator;
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = getJWTFromRequest(request);
        if(StringUtils.hasText(token) && tokenGenerator.validateToken(token)) {
            String username = tokenGenerator.getUsernameFromJWT(token);

            UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()
            );
            authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJWTFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**JwtAuthEntryPoint**

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response
                .sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**JWTGenerator**

```
@Component
public class JWTGenerator {
    private static final Key key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512);

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        Date expireDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + SecurityConstants.JWT_EXPIRATION);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expireDate)
                .signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
                .compact();
    }

    public String getUsernameFromJWT(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(key)
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts.parserBuilder()
                    .setSigningKey(key)
                    .build()
                    .parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(
                    "JWT was expired or incorrect", ex.fillInStackTrace()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthEntryPoint jwtAuthEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(
                        (exception)-> exception
                                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthEntryPoint)
                )
                .sessionManagement((session) ->
                        session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) ->
                        auth
                                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/manage/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean public JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JWTAuthenticationFilter();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have implemented a custom JWT authentication which is bad practice by probably following some poor tutorial and not read the spring security documentation of the typical authentication methods that are available. Handing out JWTs to browsers is not encouraged, and that is why there is no implementation for it in spring security. So why have you built a custom security solution?

Comment: you also have TWO authentication schemas, basic and your custom, you have not defined witch one you are authenticating with, basic auth uses cookies, your custom one takes a authrization header. You have not shown what your request looks like, if you are supplying a cookie or a header, and also you havn't even enabled debug logs and included your logs into your question.

Comment: @Toerktumlare could You please help me then? Yes I followed tutorial and then by myself I tried some things(like cookie and product). Could You please tell me more what should I change or at least send me the link to article that says how it should work? I am new to spring boot and it was my first security program. Thanks

Comment: @Toerktumlare you said that I have custom JWT authentication. Should I delete then this class? And which authentication schema should I choose?

Comment: @Toerktumlare And if You say so, then what I should use instead of JWT Token?

Comment: @Toerktumlare does it really matter?. I am new to this and I asked for help just to know what should I change. I mean we're all here to learn something and give our knowledge to other programmers. And There is no a lot of materials of spring boot security with mongo db especially so.

Comment: yes it matters because us that are here to answer question dont have time to have long conversations, long threads, we are here on our SPARE TIME to answer well defined questions and give a SINGLE well defined answer. So yes it matters, if you are seeking long term help, or mentoring etc stack overflow is not place to ask then i encourage you to find a forum or a discord instead. have a nice day. As i already have suggested, you SHOULD read the official documentation before asking questions because it is clear you havnt done that.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I do understand your frustration. And I am currently reading spring documentation, but Could You only tell me why I should not use the JWT. Correct I did not find it in spring security, but as I read on internet there's a lot of people or pages recommending it. Have a nice day!

Comment: just google why you shouldnt use JWTs as sessions, there is litteraly 1000s of webpages out there, there are litteraly 1000s of questions on stack overflow explaining why you shouldn't use JWTs as sessions.

Answer (score 0):

One of the settings you defined for your cookie is `secure` flag: `cookie.setSecure(true);`. Secure flag allows the cookie to only be sent with `https` - see [here](https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/SecureCookieAttribute). Since you are on a localhost and work with `http` cookie won't be sent, hence no authorization.

Just comment that line out.

Comment: @J Asgarov Thanks for answer. I did comment that line, but it`s still do not work. Do You have any tips left? I do also type no auth in authorization In postman is it correct? Thank You for answer!

Comment: in postman you would have to manually copy the cookies from the response and set them for every subsequent request... - perhaps try with the browser to make sure it works at all

Comment: @J Asgarov I check my postman and it was weird I don't know why but the "Expires" of cookie was set to the date of creation, but even when I changed it there is still authorization problem

Comment: @J Asgarov I did it but it`s still do not work